# how to set selected value in sap.m.searchfield ui5

Tags: sapui5

I have used a sap.m.SearchField in(SAPUI5),

Now I want to set one of the suggestion item as selected, I mean I want to set a default value to the search field.

How to set selected value in sap.m.SearchField?

Comment: Are you looking for this: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.m.SearchField.html#setValue.

Answer (score 0):

While defining [`SearchField`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.SearchField.html) itself you can set the value.

```
var oSearchField = new sap.m.SearchField({
  value: "samplePreText"
});
```

If you plan to change on some event:

```
oSearchField.setValue("samplePreText");
```